# Xamarin.Android Set SetBackground layout

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I would like to dynamically set the background (.png) .
This background.png is Embedded Resource (not in Resource/Drawable)

How can I set this background (convert to drawable) ?

```
var layout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.id_home);
layout.Background=
```

Is there a method of setting the background by the parameter stream?

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Graphics.Drawables.Drawable.CreateFromStream/p/System.IO.Stream/System.String/

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Drawable` from a `Stream`

Note: You will have to adjust which assembly you are pulling the `EmbeddedResource` from.

```
var currentAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
using (var stream = currentAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream("BackgroundLayout.background.jpg"))
{
    Drawable drawable = Drawable.CreateFromStream(stream, "SO");
    var layout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.id_home);
    layout.Background = drawable;
}
```